# SQL Query for related Table with pair of id´s from another table (show names instead id´s)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys, relational-database

I have two related Tables. The first table (tbl1) is like

### ID  |  name

- 1    |      X
- 2    |      Y
- .    |      .
- .    |      .
- .    |      .

And the second table (tbl2)

### ID1  |  ID2

- 2     |     1
- .     |     .
- .     |     .
- .     |     .

So, I try to write a SQL Query to show me the names like this:

### Name1  |  Name2

- Y       |      X
- .       |      .
- .       |      .
- .       |      .

I tried this SQL:

```
SELECT tbl1.name, tbl1.name FROM tbl2
INNER JOIN tbl1 ON tbl2.id_tbl1 = tbl1.id
INNER JOIN tbl1 AS t1 ON tbl2.id_tbl1 = t1.id;
```

But it doesn´t work.
Can someone show me a SQL Query for my problem please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two joins are the right way to go.  But you need to refer to the aliases:

```
SELECT t1_1.name, t1_2.name
FROM tbl2 t2 JOIN
     tbl1 t1_1
     ON t2.id_tbl1 = t1_1.id JOIN
     tbl1 t1_2 
     ON t2.id_tbl1 = t1_2.id;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This solution works perfect for me.